Difference between the sphere and an ellipsoid as smooth manifolds
The two sphere is compact smooth orientable surface of genus zero, and it is the unique such surface. However, an ellipsoid is also a compact smooth orientable surface of genus zero. Hence as smooth manifolds they must be isomorphic. However, they are clearly different things. How do I make sense of this?
One clear difference between them is their curvature, with the sphere having constant curvature, and an ellipsoid not. Hence I guess that a different choice of metric, or a different choice of connection, is what is going on here.

What is the question?

Is the difference between these two spaces a different choice of Riemannian metric?

If you see these surfaces as embedded in ${\mathbb R}^3$, their metric is the metric induced by the metric of ${\mathbb R}^3$. They are obviously two different Riemannian metrics. It would be interesting to project the ellipsoid on a concentric sphere and to compute the new metric on the same smooth manifold.

The sphere is diffeomorphic to the ellipsoid. But they're not isometric when considered with their respective induced Riemannian metrics from $\Bbb R^3$. When you say "they must be isomorphic" you need to be clear about which category are you in.

@Ivo: How does the line "as smooth manifolds they must be isomorphic" not tell you that this is an isomorphism in the category of smooth manifolds? Is this really an honest comment?

It does, but this is the point: you say that that "as smooth manifolds they must be isomorphic" and then say that they are clearly different -- you "can't" just change the category where you are like that and then wonder what is wrong. They are not isomorphic in the category of Riemannian manifolds (the morphisms being just metric-preserving smooth maps).

To emphasize my point, fix a diffeomorphism from the eliipsoid to the sphere, and pullback the standard round metric. With this metric, the ellipsoid is isomorphic to the sphere with its round metric, in the Riemannian category, essentially by default. But with the induced metric from $\Bbb R^3$, the ellipsoid is no longer isomorphic to the sphere with round metric in the Riemannian category.

To emphasize: "Different" surfaces can certainly be "isomorphic" — homeomorphic, diffeomorphic. If you mean isomorphic in the category of Riemannian manifolds, then the word is isometric.
